# Google Nest camera events not published to device-access console topic

Tags: nest-device-access

The Pub/Sub Subscription doesn't contain Nest camera events.

I created a Pub/Sub Subscription in the google cloud console but is not receiving any messages.

I issued the sdm api listDevices command, but no events were generated into the topic.

If I check the Subscription in the cloud console, it contains 0 messages.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a couple of reasons that may be causing this issue :

- The subscription might not be created properly. You can make use of either of the options to create a subscription :

  ```
  (i) Use the cloud shell to create the subscription (https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/subscribe-to-events#create_a_pull_subscription). 

  (ii) Use of the UI in the subscription page in Google Cloud Console to create a subscription.
  ```
- The events might not be there hence you are not seeing anything as part of the Pub/Sub.

Also, if you are using a camera make sure you are able to trigger the events that essentially comes from traits that generates events ( [CameraMotion](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/camera-motion), [CameraPerson](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/camera-person), [CameraSound](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/camera-sound)).